# Why people entering from category page goes to the homepage of my e-commerce as the second step of journey?

Tags: user-behavior, reports, data-analysis, google-analytics

I'm trying to understand some data that I have on my hands. I intend to make a deep analysis but for this, I want to create a list of probable reasons that users take some actions. Then I can track different thing and test different strategies to have the right answer.

And I need your help to create this list of probabilities.

Let's go to the data:
I lose 50% of the users that enter through any category page (product list) on my e-commerce and 40.5% these 50% that stay on my website goes to the home page.

The question is: Why? What could be the reasons to do it?

Comment: Maybe the category page they land on doesn't fit (or doesn't _obviously_ fit) what they want to do/buy (assuming they actually _want_ something, and haven't just landed on your site by accident) so they go to the home page to start looking for a better fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because they are not happy with the results on that page. Either they are trying to see what sort of company that is or they are trying to see what else the site has to offer. The question here could be of trust - is the product and the site reliable to make a purchase.

What happens after they visit the Homepage could be your answer.

Comment: Good alternatives, thanks.
When on the homepage after entered from the category page, we lose 25%. Is not big. But I believe that normal behaviour should go to the product page.